# Are either of these definitions for connectedness correct?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, definition, connectedness

In the textbook, Mathematical Tools for Physicists ([page 595 of this Google Books preview](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjbirrYlrP2AhUpyzgGHbxSAxcQzo4CKAB6BAgcEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2FMathematical_Tools_for_Physicists.html%3Fid%3DV7dUONBrHF0C%26printsec%3Dfrontcover%26source%3Dkp_read_button%26hl%3Den%26newbks%3D1%26newbks_redir%3D1&usg=AOvVaw25U56CUQAmurRqE-PFedF-)), the two following definitions are given for connected sets:

1. A set $A\subset X$ is connected iff there do not exist open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ with $A\subset U\cup V$, $A\cap U\neq\emptyset$, $A\cap V\neq\emptyset$, and $A\cap U\cap V=\emptyset$.
2. $A\subset X$ is connected iff the only subsets of $A$ that are both open and closed in the relative topology of $A$ are $\emptyset$ and $A$.

The textbook claims that these are equivalent definitions, however consider the following counter example:

\begin{align}
X&=\{1,2,3,4\}\\
A&=\{1,2\}\\
T_{X}&=\{\emptyset,X,U,V\}\\
T_{A}&=\{\emptyset,A,\{1\},\{2\}\}\\
U&=\{1,3\}\\
V&=\{2,4\}
\end{align}

With the above domain of discourse, definition 2. is made true, yet definition 1. is made false. Thus the definitions are not equivalent.

Since the book claims that they are equivalent, but they are not, and there is only one definition for connected set up to equivalence, at least one of them must be wrong. The question is, which one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are both open and closed subsets of $A$: Each is the complement of the other and complements of open sets are closed.

Comment: Ah, you are right, and I don't seem to be able to modify the counter example to make it work again. Thank you. 

I still don't know how to prove they are equivalent, I have only succeeded in doing it one direction (1.$\rightarrow$2.). I thought the reason it didn't go both ways was because of my incorrect counter example, but asking for help with that is another question.